# Set Id Not found for application Belonging to

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, xml

I have been looking for a way to understand what set ids are. I worked on this website were set id gives i and my colleagues problems. I get messages like this " Message : nullER0001;Authentication Failed, Username or Password Incorrect;
Status : 500
Code : 10
Time : 01-02-2023 16:22:23
" whenever i try to process an application. I can't seem to find where the set id is in the code. i am also confused if this is an html problem, css error, java script error of python code error.

I tried to modify the html code and I also tried to clear the cache on js.